# Method listed twice in JavaDoc

Tags: java, javadoc

I have two classes and two interfaces. `InterfaceA`

```
package ch.sukha.testmachine.client;
interface InterfaceA {
    /**
     * Foo.
     */
    void foo();
}
```

is the super interface of `InterfaceB`.

```
package ch.sukha.testmachine.client;
public interface InterfaceB extends InterfaceA {
   /**
    * Bar.
    */
   void bar();
}
```

Likewise, class `A` is the super class of

```
package ch.sukha.testmachine.client;
class A implements InterfaceA {
    @Override
    public void foo() {
    }
}
```

class `B`.

```
package ch.sukha.testmachine.client;
public class B extends A implements InterfaceB {
    @Override
    public void bar() {
    }
}
```

In the generated JavaDoc, method `foo` appears twice.

[image]

Comment: Your javadoc shows B extends Object, which does not match your code. Have you tried re-generating the javadoc?

Comment: That's correct because A is not exported. I want to create multiple subclasses of A and reuse the documentation of InterfaceA.

Comment: have you tried to use `@Override` in front of the interface methods? you should use this anyway for a better code style.

Comment: @jlordo: Thanks! Exporting InterfaceA fixes the JavaDoc. Do you know why that is? But now the documentation of InterfaceB is split up. That's why I'd rather not export it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A is not exported. I want to create multiple subclasses of A and reuse
>   the documentation of InterfaceA.

Export everything to JavaDoc.

To reuse parts of it, you can use the

```
@inheritDoc
```

annotation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was looking for something like that.